# Conditional Probability: $P(A|B) = P(A|C_i)P(C_i|B)$

Tags: probability

basic refresher question about Conditional Probability: 
Can someone please provide a basic proof of the following identity:

In the discrete case:
$P(A|B) = \sum_{i} P(A|C_i)P(C_i|B)$

In the continuous case:
$P(A|B) = \int P(A|C)P(C|B)dC$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When you ask a question on this site, you are also expected to show your efforts. These basic questions can easily be searched on the web

Answer (score 1):

You left out one *important* detail.   The sequence: $\{C_i\}$ must partition $B$ for this to be true.   (IE: they must be mutually exclusive and exhaustive subsets).   That is:

- $\forall i\forall j\; \big( i\neq j \;\to\; C_i\cap C_j =\varnothing\big)$
- $\bigcup_i C_i = B$

Then we have: $\forall i \; \big(C_i\cap B= C_i\big)$ , and so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B)
& = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap\bigcup_i C_i)}{\mathsf P(B)} \\[1ex] ~ & = {\sum}_i\; \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap C_i)}{\mathsf P(B)} \\[1ex] ~ & = {\sum}_i\frac{\mathsf P(A\mid C_i)\mathsf P(C_i)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\[1ex] ~ & = {\sum}_i\mathsf P(A\mid C_i)\mathsf P(C_i\mid B) \\[1ex]\Box\end{align}$$

And analogously for the continuous case.