# Conditional Probability: $P(A|B) = P(A|C_i)P(C_i|D_j)\cdots P(K_z|B)$?

Tags: probability

A basic identity in conditional probability is (under certain assumptions), 
[see the following Math Stack Exchange question:
[Conditional Probability: $P(A|B) = P(A|C_i)P(C_i|B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447640/conditional-probability-pab-pac-ipc-ib) ] :
$$P(A|B) = \sum_{i} P(A|C_i)\cdot P(C_i|B)$$

Can we make some assumptions similar to the simplified case referenced in the linked post: {$C_i$} partitions $B$, {$D_j$} also partitions $B$, and different subsets of {$D$} partition each $C_i$. 
Can we then generalize the simplified case to something like:
$$P(A|B) = \sum_{m}\sum_{n} I_{mn}\cdot P(A|C_n)\cdot P(C_n|D_m)\cdot P(D_m|B)$$ 
where $I_{mn}$ is an indicator function that is $1$ if $D_m$ is in the set of D that partitions $C_n$, or $0$ otherwise.

Can conditional probabilities be chained together this way? [Note: this post is similar to the linked post, but this is not a repeat. This post is asking about a potential generalization of the linked post.]

Comment: How could this be true "in general" if the less complex is only true "under certain assumptions"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've listed the assumptions explicitly and reworded the question for clarity.